# Format Cart Totals HTML from JSON Response

Tags: cart, ajax, totals, json

**My Controller File**

```
public function myAction() {


        $response = array();
        $response['myresponse'] = $this->myAjax();
        $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
        return $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($response));
    }



    protected function myAjax()
    {

        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $totalsBlock = $layout->createBlock('checkout/cart_totals')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/totals.phtml');
        return $totalsBlock->toHtml();
    }
```

**My JSON Response**

`{"myresponse":"    <table id=\"shopping-cart-totals-table\">\n        <col \/>\n        <col width=\"1\" \/>\n        <tfoot>\n            <tr>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"1\">\n        <strong>Grand Total<\/strong>\n    <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\">\n        <strong><span class=\"price\">$90.56<\/span><\/strong>\n    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n        <\/tfoot>\n        <tbody>\n            <tr>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"1\">\n        Subtotal    <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\">\n        <span class=\"price\">$820.56<\/span>    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n<tr>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\" colspan=\"1\">\n        Shipping &amp; Handling (Flat Rate - Fixed)    <\/td>\n    <td style=\"\" class=\"a-right\">\n        <span class=\"price\">$90.00<\/span>    <\/td>\n<\/tr>\n<tr>\n   <\/tr>\n        <\/tbody>\n    <\/table>\n"}`

**My Oncomplete function**

```
new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $formAction;?>", {
           method: 'post',
           postBody: "mypostdata="+$('my_value').value,
           onComplete: function(data) {
                var mydata = data.responseText.evalJSON(true);
                $('shopping-cart-totals-table').update(mydata);
            }
    });
```

The cart totals block is being updated but with incorrect HTML format. How could I make it in formatted data and show proper HTML in cart totals block ?

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
$('shopping-cart-totals-table').update(mydata);
```

Try using

```
$('shopping-cart-totals-table').update(mydata.myresponse);
```

You are sending JSON with the key myresponse and your cart block html as the value for that key. So mydata will be an Object after json is converted into a JS object and this object should have a property myresponse with the HTML for the cart block.

Comment: Paras, you seem logical, but how can I pass multiple parameters in `postBody`. Will it create any issue if I use your code ?

Comment: You don't have to send multiple params in postBody. Just use $('shopping-cart-totals-table').update(mydata.myresponse); in the oncomplete function.

Comment: Okay, but what if I need to send multiple params ? Is it possible in my posted code ?

Comment: Please post that as a separate question. :)

Comment: Thanks, posted pls check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33568/prototype-check-if-checkbox-is-selected-and-pass-its-value-in-params